# Combo box that presents values as ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a summary worksheet(sh) with 26000 entries. I have a userform, with a combo box that allows the user to search the database and whenever the value in the combo box matches the value in column 6; the entire row is copied to a new worksheet(shR). The entries/values in column 6 range between 0.007 and 1. I want to design my code such that the combo box presents these values as ranges and then the code can search for all such entries within that range in column 6. Below are my proposed ranges;

1. 0.007-0.1
2. 0.11-0.25
3. 0.251-0.5
4. 0.51-0.75
5. 0.751-1

And this is my current code:

```
For i=5 to totRows

    if (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 6)) <= Trim(cbDn.Value) Or cbDn.Value = "") then
        totR = shR.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shR.Cells(totR + 1, 1)
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Filter column 6 for the combo box value, then copy/paste the visible rows in one go.

Comment: That won't do it because my userform has multiple combo boxes and the user searches the data using them. All the other combo boxes work fine as I want an exact match but with column 6, I want the combo box to display as a range, hence the filter would be manual yet I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be OK:

```
Dim arr, mn, max, v, c

If Len(cbDn.Value) > 0 Then  '<<< check user made a selection

    arr = split(cbDn.Value, "-")
    mn = CDbl(Trim(arr(0))
    mx = CDbl(Trim(arr(1))
    
    For i=5 to totRows
        v = sh.Cells(i, 6).Value
        if v > mn And v <= mx then 
            Set c = shR.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=c
        End If
```

Comment: I have a follow up question though; how do I maintain the option that this combo box could still be left blank by the user as my initial code had this option i.e cbDn.value=""

Comment: That works but I'm now encountering a new problem @Tim Williams. The combo boxes are no longer exclusive such that they now give results that were not selected in the combo boxes.

Comment: That sounds like a new question.

Comment: Not precisely. When I asked the question before, I assumed plugging in back this line of code would work out fine with the other combo boxes. When you gave me the solution, I tested it in isolation. Now when I run all 7 combo boxes, there results also include values that don't match the search criterion in the combo boxes.

Comment: You only gave code for one combo box - I have no idea how you're combining this with the other selections...   The answer I gave was for the question you posted.

Comment: True. May you please help me though if you can? The code works, its just that it then adds some results that are not part of the values on the combo boxes.

Comment: Sure, but it would be best to post a new question which shows how you combine all of the different combobox selections, and maybe give some examples of data which gets copied but should not have been.